# Voxel Performance

Tags: c++, opengl, performance, minecraft-modding, voxels

So Im trying to make a minecraft style voxel game to learn OpenGL, but Im running into performance issues. I found this thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995652/3d-occlusion-culling
where the author says he's drawing 250,000 cubes with an okay framerate. However, I can do about 3000 ish with the same framerates. I found another thread in which someone said that you should combine visible faces into a mesh. Does that mean you put all the vertices into one vertex buffer? If so, how do I pass texture data?

Comment: Welcome user, this is a very broad question, too broad for the site. You need to use a profiler and find out which parts of your code are slow. Try to improve those parts, if you're unable to, then come back here with a specific question about that part of your game. Make sure to include what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: @Byte56 I think the question is OK now, even answerable.

-> Yeah, you should try to use as many batches as possible, that is, combining the more cubes you can, in the less vertex buffers you can. This is a good resource on the matter: http://0fps.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/meshing-in-a-minecraft-game/
And to use more than one texture, you can use a [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas), or even multi-texturing, though atlas will give you the best performance!

Comment: @GustavoMaciel All yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you should try to batch as much as possible, that is, combining the more cubes you can, in the least amount of vertex buffers you can. This is a good resource on the matter of [Voxel Meshing](http://0fps.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/meshing-in-a-minecraft-game). I recomend you to follow the culling algorithm, even older versions of minecraft used it and stood well at good framerates.

To use more than one texture, you can use a [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) to fake that. Some devices might even support multi-texturing in a single batch, which would be easier to work with, though the atlas will give you the best performance!

Comment: So I already use the culling method where you check all sides, but the frame rate is still pretty bad

Comment: But you are saving the whole mesh in a single batch? If you render the cubes separately, the framerate will be very low.

Comment: i guess im missing what a mesh is...but when you dynamically combine a mesh, how do you draw the different textures?

Comment: Read the last paragraph.